# Piping into rcorr

Tags: r

I am trying to run `rcorr` as part of a function over multiple dataframes, extracting p-values for each test but am receiving an NA values when piping into `rcorr`.

For example if I create a matrix and run `rcorr` on this matrix, extracting the pvalue table with `$P` and the pvalue with `[2]` it works...

```
library(Hmisc)
library(magrittr)

mt <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), ncol=2)
    rcorr(mt, type="pearson")$P[2]
    [1] 0
```

But if I try and pipe this I only recieve NAs.

```
mt %>% rcorr(., type="pearson")$P[2]
[1] NA NA

mt %>% rcorr(., type="pearson")$P
Error in .$rcorr(., type = "pearson") : 
  3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesnt work or give a workaround? Ideally I don't want to have to create variables for each of my matrices before running `rcorr`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the statement `library(Hmisc)` to the code in your question since `rcorr` is not part of base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

```
(mt %>% mcor(type = "pearson"))$P[2]
# [1] 0
```

**Explanation**

Notice that both

```
mt %>% rcorr(., type = "pearson")
```

and

```
mt %>% rcorr(type = "pearson")
```

work as expected. The problem is that you add `$` and `[` to the second object, which basically are like subsequent function calls. For instance,

```
s <- function(x) c(1, 1 + x)
1 %>% s
# [1] 1 2
```

works as expected, but

```
1 %>% s[1]
# Error in .[s, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

doesn't return `1` since we are trying to do something like `s[1](1)` instead.

Now

```
1 %>% s(x = .)[1]
# Error in .[s(x = .), 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

just as yours

```
mt %>% rcorr(., type = "pearson")$P[2]
# [1] NA NA
```

is trickier. Notice that it can be rewritten as

```
mt %>% `[`(`$`(rcorr(., type = "pearson"), "P"), 2)
# [1] NA NA
```

So, now it becomes clear that the latter doesn't work because it basically is

```
`[`(mt, `$`(rcorr(mt, type = "pearson"), "P"), 2)
# [1] NA NA
```

which, when deciphered, is

```
mt[rcorr(mt, type = "pearson")$P, 2]
# [1] NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A tidy solution, at least I hope!

```
library(dplyr) 
library(broom) 
library(Hmisc) 

mtcars[, 5:6] %>%
as.matrix()%>%
rcorr()%>%
tidy() %>%
select(estimate)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using `%$%` from **magrittr**:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(magrittr)
mt <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2)

mt %>% rcorr(type="pearson") %$% P[2]
[1] 0
```